# sudo -i returns an error

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, sudo

When I try to switch to root using `sudo -i` i get the error `/var/tmp/sclDvf3Vx: line 8: -i: command not found`... However, `su -` works which I will continue to use. I'm by no means a linux system administrator so the environment is still pretty foggy to me. I guess my questions are:

1. Why is the error being thrown?
2. What's the difference between the two commands?
3. Why would you use one over the other?

***Update:***

I'm using CentOS version: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Here's the output from some commands I was asked to run, in the comments below.

- `type sudo` : `sudo is /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/sudo`
- `sudo -V` : `/var/tmp/sclIU7gkA: line 8: -V: command not found`
- `grep'^root:' /etc/passwd` : `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

***Update:***

This was added to my non-root user's ~/.bashrc a while back because i needed C++11 support. When I comment it out, re-ssh in, I can run sudo -i just fine without any errors.

```
if [ "$(gcc -dumpversion)" != "4.7.2" ]; then 
  scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
fi
```

Comment: Are you sure the `-` is really an (ASCII) `-`?

Comment: Yes? o_0 Not sure if trolling or serious lol

Comment: @Dillan what is the output of `readlink -f $(type -P sudo)`?

Comment: @jordanm `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/var/tmp/sclDvf3Vx`?

Comment: Has anyone created an `alias` for your `sudo` command?

Comment: Please post the output of `type sudo`, `sudo -V` and `grep '^root:' /etc/passwd`. What version of CentOS is this on?

Comment: @chaos Each time that I try `sudo -i` it gives a different filename in `/var/tmp/`. However, the files don't exist. Since they're tmp files, maybe they're being removed after my attempts or something?

Comment: @Gilles, `type sudo`: `sudo is /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/sudo`, `sudo -V`: `/var/tmp/sclIU7gkA: line 8: -V: command not found`, `grep '^root:' /etc/passwd`: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` and CentOS version `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)`

Comment: Ok, so you have a local command called `sudo` which is not the normal sudo command. Given that it doesn't understand sudo's options, it's clearly not some standard thing. Either use `/usr/bin/sudo` or ask your local administrators (who should really have told you about this when they gave you sudo powers).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is a VPS I purchased for the sake of learning :p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns some unknown, probably home-grown program, which the internet cannot help with.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what lead you to think that? Just curious. Devtoolset or?

Comment: I don't think this is home-grown at all, it's CentOS's version of [RH Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/): http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/ . Presumably *someone* on the internet does know about it.

Comment: centos7 - can't believe this is still an issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the comments and your further investigations it looks like your devtoolset is modifying the `PATH`. Unfortunately that includes what appears to be an old or broken sudo command.

It would be worth trying to modify the devtoolset include in your `.bashrc` like this, and then logging back in again:

```
if [ "$(gcc -dumpversion)" != "4.7.2" ]; then 
  scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
  PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH    # We need a working sudo
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than work around the SCL's broken sudo wrapper, I just disabled it.

```
echo >> /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/sudo
chmod -x /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/sudo
```

Adding a newline to the end of the file ensures it won't get overwritten by subsequent Yum updates, and then I just make it non-executable.

I installed the dev toolset to get modern versions of gcc and c++ on RHEL 6, and have had no issues compiling code without the fake sudo in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with `sudo -E` flag after using devtoolset-4. You should not add `-E` flag in that case, because it is added in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/bin/sudo` wrapper script, here is the contents of it:

```
#! /bin/sh
# TODO: parse & pass-through sudo options from $@
sudo_options="-E"

for arg in "$@"
do
   case "$arg" in
    *\'*)
      arg= ;;
   esac
   cmd_options="$cmd_options '$arg'" 
done
exec /usr/bin/sudo $sudo_options LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=$PATH scl enable devtoolset-4 "$cmd_options"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was reported to RedHat in [BZ1319936](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1319936) and fixed in devtoolset devtoolset-9-9.0-3.el7 ([RHEA-2019:4132](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2019:4132)).

Comment: It's broken again in devtoolset-11 and 12